# Should I spread connections into a stack of switches

Tags: switch, netgear-prosafe

I have a managed stack of Netgear GS752TPS switches that are joined together into a single stack using fibre.

I also have - for example - a terminal server with four NICs using teaming. I also have other servers etc but using this as an example, should I spread the connections between the switches 1, 2, 3, and 4 or is the difference negligible from putting all four into switch 1?

The patch panel connections are spread between the four.

Comment: This would depend on the type of link aggregation (what you refer to as teaming) you are using and possibly the capabilities of the switches you are using. On a quick review of the docs, I was unable to determine on a quick review if this platform supports LAG across the stack or not.

Comment: I believe the switches do support LAG - although it hasn't been changed from the factory defaults.

Comment: I know they support LAG. The question is whether all the ports must be on the same switch or if they can be spread across the stack. Of course, if you haven't configured anything on the switches, you are using one of the "teaming" modes that doesn't require switch side configuration.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely spread hosts across stacks where possible. This eliminates the switch from being a single point of failure.

As stacked switches have dual rings they avoid being a single point of failure (provided that all hosts are connected to a minimum of two switches in the stack.)

Comment: Yes - I can see that from a resiliancy point - although if one of the switches went it'd be a fun time for all anyway! Do you think the _performance_ difference would be negligible?

Comment: So long as none of the switches and their uplinks are being hammered, you won't notice a difference.